# Помогите дописать функцию с оператором

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```js
var txt = $(".error").text() || "Текста нет";
$('input.button.btn-cart').click(function() {

  if (txt == "Текста нет") {
    //тут я полагаю нужно как то заставить еще раз txt присвоить .text()
  }

  $.stickr({
    note: txt,
    className: 'message-cart',
    position: {
      right: 0,
      bottom: 0
    },
    time: 3000,
    speed: 300
  });
});
```

Ребят помогите дописать скрипт, логика такова:

1) присваиваем `txt` то что лежит в `.error` в формате `.text()` если оно пустое присвоим `"текста нет"`

2) После клика по буттону проверяем `txt` равен `"текста нет"` ?

2.1) Если равен то еще раз принудительно присваиваем `txt` то что лежит в `.error` в формате `.text()`, Причем это нужно выполнить с задержкой так как клик по буттону вызывает еще одну функцию которая кладет в  DOM данные для `.error`

2.2) Если что то другое то выполняемым скрипт дальше.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, хорошо было бы увидеть HTML который Вы используете.

Во-вторых никогда не стоит присваивать значения в духе "Текста нет", или "Неверно", для это есть стандартные средства языка. Присвойте FALSE и проверка в if сразу станет красивой и однозначной

```
if (!txt) {
  // do something
}
```

В-третьих, вызывать функцию "с задержкой" это неправильный подход, необходимо вызывать всю эту проверку как callback функции которая у Вас "кладет в DOM данные для .error".

Таким образом, Вам необходимо весь вышеописанный код просто завернуть в функцию с именем, например, check_error

```
function check_error() {// Код из Вашего примера}
```

В случае если txt == FALSE вызываете функцию, которая кладёт что-то в .error и после этого на .success (если это асинхронный запрос) или любой другой доступный колбек присваиваете $('.error').value() = txt;

Comment: куда правильно будет записать `callback()` в этом коде http://jsfiddle.net/znkhany8/

Comment: еще раз вчитавшись в сообщение - понял следующие http://jsfiddle.net/znkhany8/2/ но не нечего не работает...